# Can Windows identity (Windows integrated auth) and Azure AD OpenId apply together to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application where Windows Authentication is enabled. I have added Azure AD authentication with opened in the same app but it won't do silent authentication after expiration. I found it is because the ASP.NET MVC app enables Windows authentication. It won't trigger the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` auto-trigger method. Does anybody know how this method auto-starts my silent authentication work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can SAML auth cookies create problem ? it won't allow onauthorization code received fire

Answer (score 0):

The SITMinder Cookies create a problem when I verified there are two identities one is Siteminderand the other is cookies. Siteminder creates an issue as its validity is more than the Azure AD token. MSAL may be assuming that identity is not expired hence it won't trigger the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived